# Undefined references in a project using libcurl

Tags: c++, reference, undefined, codeblocks, libcurl

I have a problem with libcurl. I am writing a program to get a text file from an ftp site. First I wrote a test project and it worked. Then I created a new working project and it gives me a bunch of undefined reference errors. I use exactly the same settings but one is working and another one is not!

The issue log:

[image]

All dll files are copied into the project directories. My settings:

[image]

and (in Linker I linked it to \lib)

[image]

and

[image]

It is unbelievable how much troubles I have after Java. ((

Thank you all if you could help!

Comment: You are not linking with the Windows Socket Library, I suspect.

Comment: Mat, sorry. I tried to change it but I guess it did not change.

Comment: Mats Petersson. How can I solve it?

Comment: @IgorTupitsyn You might find ***[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243638/adding-static-libcurl-to-codeblocks-ide?rq=1)*** helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you are missing the Widows Socket library.

To fix it, go to your linker settings and add a library that is called "**libws2_32.a**" to the list of link libraries. Of course, you have to find the proper one on your disk first, but if your build environment is set up properly, then adding the name (no path) should be enough.

Comment: No, it's not part of either Windows or libcurl. It should have been part of your development environment (i.e. the GCC distribution you got.) What are you using anyways? MinGW? What's your IDE (I don't recognize the screenshots, but that doesn't mean much.)

Comment: @IgorTupitsyn: Did you just delete one of your comments?! What happened? Is your problem solved? In any case, you shouldn't have deleted it after I responded to it!

Comment: yzt. Sorry! I first wrote that I could not find it but then I searched my hard drive and found it in MinGW. So, I deleted the first comment. THANK YOU SO MUCH, everyone! It does work now!