# Static linking OpenSSL and cURL with Autotools and MinGW

Tags: c++, openssl, codeblocks, libcurl, static-linking

I'm trying to build a statically linked OpenSSL + LibCurl console application with CodeBlocks. However, I can't get it to work. I keep getting these errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Filer (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib\libcurl.a(libcurl_la-openssl.o)|| undefined reference to `SSL_get0_alpn_selected'|
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib\libcurl.a(libcurl_la-openssl.o)|| undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos'|
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib\libcurl.a(libcurl_la-openssl.o)|| undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb'|
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib\libcurl.a(libcurl_la-openssl.o)|| undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_srp_username'|
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib\libcurl.a(libcurl_la-openssl.o)|| undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_srp_password'|
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib\libcurl.a(libcurl_la-openssl.o)|| undefined reference to `SSL_COMP_free_compression_methods'|
||=== Build failed: 6 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

This is the build log:

```
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Filer.exe "obj\Debug\MinGW Sources\BASE64\base64.o
" "obj\Debug\MinGW Sources\SQLite\sqlite3.o" obj\Debug\Users\thoma\Desktop\Filer
\main.o  -static  -lcurl -lrtmp -lidn -lssl -lssh2 -lcrypto -lz -lwldap32 -lws2_
32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib\libcrypto.dll.a C:\MinGW\msys\1.0
\local\lib\libcurl.a C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib\libcurl.dll.a C:\MinGW\msys\1.0
\local\lib\libssl.a C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib\libssl.dll.a C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\l
ocal\lib\libwxjpeg-3.0.a C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib\libwxpng-3.0.a C:\MinGW\msy
s\1.0\local\lib\libwxscintilla-3.0.a C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib\libwxtiff-3.0.a
 C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib\libz.a C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib\libz.dll.a
```

I have used the set-up which is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243638/adding-static-libcurl-to-codeblocks-ide).

Some pictures of my setup:

[image] [image] [image][image][image]

Comment: Does your command line have a `-L<path to curl library folder>`?

Comment: @user4581301, no not that I can find? I have added the build log and some pictures of the set-up

Comment: Command line looks a bit odd. `-lcurl` says link in curl, but without a `-L` to tell the linker where to find it game over. See if there is anything on the Search Directories tab  that will allow you to specify the Linker search directories. On the other hand, you've specified the exact location of what looks like the linking information for the shared library version. Since you want static linking I think you can live without that.

Comment: Also be certain that you have static libraries. Last time I played with cURL and SSL under mingw (a few years ago, mind you) I had to build the suckers.

Comment: @user4581301, I have build the static libs? like libcurl.a and libssl.a?

Comment: @user4581301 see last new 2 photo's for my search directory settings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145485/discussion-between-tva-van-hesteren-and-user4581301).

Comment: @user4581301, I have added the default lib directory to the linker search directories, which shortens the error list, see updated list above

Comment: Looks good. All you need to do now is track down those hold out libraries and add their paths to the Search Directories list. I won't be much help to you from here on in, though. I have no idea where you will find them if they aren't in with the rest of the libraries and I'm not familiar enough with them to provide building instructions.

Comment: @user4581301, alright, so do you have any idea what these files have to be names at all?

Comment: @user4581301, I got one step further again, I now get this error list, see updated question

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren - Please edit the question, and add the output of `cat "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\include\opensslconf.h"`. The output of `egrep '(COMP|ALPN|SRP)' "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\include\opensslconf.h"`, may be helpful, too (but the same information is available in the `cat`).

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch between your OpenSSL version and the OpenSSL version used by libcurl.

Comment: Alright, that seems relevant. How can I fix this issue and how can I validate both used versions ?

Comment: You want me to rebuild my setup?

Comment: Solving it is actually very tricky and you will likely have to recompile `libcurl` itself.

Comment: Oke, I can of course re-compile lib curl, however how do I delete the old version of libcurl and OpenSSL in it's entire?

Comment: That would be another question.

Comment: Because just deleting the dirs in \lib won't be enough I guess

Comment: `SSL_get_alpn_selected_cb`, `SSL_get0_alpn_selected` and friends are available in OpenSSL 1.0.2 and OpenSSL 1.1.0. Its not clear to me how you are arriving at the mismatched versions conclusion. You should probably explain your position. My guess (and its just a guess), is OpenSSL was configured with `no-alpn`, `no-srp` and others in one library, but they are missing from another one.

Comment: @jww, currently I'm starting from scratch. Trying to build zlib as a start, but it returns met the error in msys: `cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin': No such file or directory`. I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA/mingw64_how_to.html#libz). BTW, the patch is not working for me, returns me: `make: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: Command not found` but without the patch it runs?

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren - MinGW is not my specialty (I'm an OpenSSL guy). I've had so much trouble in the past with MinGW I don't want to be near it. I no longer test any libraries on it. Luckily for me, MinGW was abandoned by its authors some time ago, so it was not hard to justify the position.

Comment: You might consider using Cygwin. Cygwin is still actively maintained. You might also consider creating a script to manually build the libraries from the command line. You can find a couple to get you started at [Build-Scripts](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts). The Git build script builds about 10 libraries needed by Git, including OpenSSL and cURL.

Comment: @jww, Yea I know, however I need to be able to build against Linux, Windows but also against Mac. Which is not supported by Cygwin?

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren - Which platform are you missing from Linux, Windows and Mac? MACs are closer to the BSDs. Use NetBSD to simulate a Mac. Use Clang on Linux to simulate the Apple Clang compiler. In the past, I used [Hackintosh](http://www.hackintosh.com/) to provide an OS X virtual machine (before I bought a Mac Book). You will need a copy of OS X to do it, though.